# how to fetch html object attribute in jQuery using this

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fetch text field attribute on autocomplete event in JQuery using `this`. But I am not able to fetch the value. 
My logic is when I type three letter in any of the above text field it will invoke the below fuction on autocomplete and i will fetch `alt` attribute in alert, but it is showing `undefined`. Can anyone please help me.

Code is given below.
In My HTML:

```
<input type="text" alt="wwww"  value="1234" name="xyzah" id="xyza" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz"   value="1235" name="zqabqwx" id="zqab" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz1"  value="1235" name="csqvo7jkd" id="csqv" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz2"  value="1235" name="lewcwsder" id="lewc" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz3"  value="1235" name="xxndjshey" id="xxnd" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz4"  value="1235" name="veqfhsyeq" id="veqf" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz5"  value="1235" name="okryertshsw" id="okr" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz6"  value="1235" name="rrqpjduewq" id="rrqp" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz7"  value="1235" name="solqjduetw" id="solq" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz8"  value="1235" name="pkoqieodhe" id="pkoq" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz9"  value="1235" name="locjodyewq" id="locj" />
```

in jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(this).autocomplete({ 
      source: function(request, response) { 
      alert("alt=="+$(this).attr("alt"));
      $.ajax({
      url: "../controller/action",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
      term: request.term,
      },
      success: function(data) {
      response(data)
      },
     cache: false
     });

     },    
     minLength: 3
     });
   });
```

Comment: Why are you doing `$(this).autocomplete`? You should bind the plugin to a input, not to the document.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `source` callback, `this` refers to the widget object not the target dom reference. So you can use

```
this.element.attr("alt")
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[id^="loc"]').each(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        console.log()
        alert("alt==" + this.element.attr("alt"));
      },
      minLength: 3
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" alt="wwww" value="1234" name="LocASearch" id="loca" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz" value="1235" name="LocbSearch" id="locb" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz1" value="1235" name="LocbSearch1" id="locv" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz2" value="1235" name="LocbSearch2" id="locc" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz3" value="1235" name="LocbSearch3" id="locd" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz4" value="1235" name="LocbSearch4" id="locf" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz5" value="1235" name="LocbSearch5" id="loce" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz6" value="1235" name="LocbSearch6" id="locg" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz7" value="1235" name="LocbSearch7" id="loch" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz8" value="1235" name="LocbSearch8" id="loci" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz9" value="1235" name="LocbSearch9" id="locj" />
```

Comment: It is not like, every time id will started with "loc". i have edited my post.

Comment: Calling directly `$('input[id^="loc"]').autocomplete` is enough. No need to loop through each input, and then do `$(this).autocomplete`

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos I just built on top of what OP had... assuming that code was already in a context where `this` was referring to a single input element.. then to make my demo work wrapped it in a each loop

Comment: @AnishRanjanDandapat you need to have some logical way to know which input elements to target... that is the part where you need to comeup with a selector to target the right elements... this answer does not cover that part... it just tried to get you the `alt` attribute of the current element in the `source` callback... An easy solution to the selector problem is to add a common class to all the elements to be targeted and then use a class selector

Comment: @Arun P Johny my text fiel id will not always started with 'loc'. it that case what is the way

Comment: @AnishRanjanDandapat as I said in the previous comment give a common class to all the input elements

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<input type="text" alt="wwww"  value="1234" name="xyzah" id="xyza" class="load" />
<input type="text" alt="xyz"   value="1235" name="zqabqwx" id="zqab" class="load"/>
<input type="text" alt="xyz1"  value="1235" name="csqvo7jkd" id="csqv" class="load"/>
<input type="text" alt="xyz2"  value="1235" name="lewcwsder" id="lewc" class="load"/>
<input type="text" alt="xyz3"  value="1235" name="xxndjshey" id="xxnd" class="load"/>
<input type="text" alt="xyz4"  value="1235" name="veqfhsyeq" id="veqf" class="load"/>
<input type="text" alt="xyz5"  value="1235" name="okryertshsw" id="okr" class="load"/>
<input type="text" alt="xyz6"  value="1235" name="rrqpjduewq" id="rrqp" class="load"/>
<input type="text" alt="xyz7"  value="1235" name="solqjduetw" id="solq" class="load"/>
<input type="text" alt="xyz8"  value="1235" name="pkoqieodhe" id="pkoq" class="load"/>
<input type="text" alt="xyz9"  value="1235" name="locjodyewq" id="locj" class="load"/>

$(function() {
    $('.load').each(function(index, value) {
        $(value).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            console.log($(value).attr("alt"))
        },
        minLength: 3
    });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do for you. You just need to bind your event correctly to the input.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $(':text').each(function() {
      $(this).autocomplete({ 
      source: function(request, response) { 
      alert("alt=="+$(this).attr("alt"));
      $.ajax({
      url: "../controller/action",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
      term: request.term,
      },
      success: function(data) {
      response(data)
      },
     cache: false
     });

     },    
     minLength: 3
     });
    });
  });
```